# Is there a environmental variable named AWS_REGION available in all aws service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I [know](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime) that there is an environment variable AWS_REGION in AWS Lambda. Is there a similar variable available by default in the other AWS services like EMR or EC2 instances?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: You can get that value on EC2 via the metadata API.

Comment: Why do you ask? What are you wanting to achieve?